When was Venom (aka The Legend of Spider Forest) released?
The horror movie Venom (aka The Legend of Spider Forest) came up under another question but I couldn't figure out when it was released. Some sources say 1971, others 1974, and some both.

Amazon: 1971.

Google widget: 1974

Wikipedia, both:

Venom (1971 film)
Venom is a 1974 British horror film directed by Peter Sykes and starring Simon Brent and Neda Arnerić.



Of course, some movies do have multiple release dates (e.g., different regional releases, translations, formats) but I didn't see any specifics to explain this discrepancy; I think it could even be the result of a typo being spread around, so I'm looking for something solid. What's the right date?

"Filming took place in October 1970" - educated guess would be that 1971 was when the movie was filmed and cut, and then release was delayed (given that according to Wikipedia the film lead to a job offer for the director in 1972). It does seem to happen that production date and release date are some time apart.

IMDb says 1971, and there's a note that suggests a later release in the US.
